# Keep div height while the image is loading

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a square image within `.img-container`. Sometimes it takes a few seconds for an image to load and the `.img-container` collapses and only takes the full height when the image loads. However, I would like it to keep the full height (as if the image is there) while the image is loading.

I would've easily done this by setting a `min-height` on `img-container` class, however it's a fluid grid and the image is responsive (notice bootstrap's `img-responsive` helper class) which makes it hard to set the min-height to an appropriate value for different screen sizes (although achievable with media queries as a last resort).
Solving this by putting a placeholding image sounds like an overkill (especially performance wise on mobile). Also, not sure what would load first then, the placeholder image or the actual image.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card">
      <span class="img-container thumbnail clearfix">
        <img alt class="pull-left img-responsive" src="http://...">
      </span>
      <div class="caption">
        <a href="http://.." class="card-title lead">
          Some text
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Upvoted, not because of the problem and solution, but because "min-height" was the answer I was after. Two birds with one stone. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**EDIT DUE TO COMMENT**

If you do not specify a source at all (not even a dummy, temporary one), the browser will not even try to "guess" the image's height, and so it collapses. If you know the ratio of the image (it's obviously 1:1 in case of a square picture), you can use the following trick to preoccupy the space, and scale the image along with the div.

Set the following CSS:

```
.test-div-inner {
    padding-bottom:100%;
    background:#EEE;
    height:0;
    position:relative;
}
.test-image {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Then you can use the following HTML:

```
<div class="test-div-inner">
    <img class="test-image" src="http://goo.gl/lO9SUU">
</div>
```

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pQ5zh/3/

*Note that the fiddle contains another `div` element, this is only required if you would like to give it all a padding or border, since the `padding-bottom` calculates the padding in pixels based on the width of the `div` **INCLUDING THOSE PARAMETERS**, which is NOT the effect we want to achieve (the image would be a little taller than it should be).*

**For non-square images:**

If you would like to change the ratio of the picture, just change the `padding-bottom` of the container `div` accordingly. For example, if you would like to place an image with a ratio of 2:1, change the padding to `50%`. To keep it short: the ratio of the container `div`'s width and padding should always be equal to the ratio of the image's width and height.

---

There is an easy way to do exactly this, but it **only works for square images**.
Specify the width of the image (using CSS) to be **100%**. This way the browser will automatically assume that the image height is the same as it's width, and preoccupy the place.

http://jsfiddle.net/pQ5zh/2/

```
.test-image {
    width:100%;
}
```

*Note: There is a way to achieve this for non-square images too, but that is a bit more complicated.*

**EDIT**: See above.

Comment: it doesn't really work. I tried removing the image source and the `.test-div` collapses in height. It should keep the height while the image is not there.

Comment: I have modified my answer to solve this and also provided a solution for non-square images.

Comment: Keep in mind this padding trick is relative to the width of the `parent` element. If this is not what you want, add a wrapper element with the target width and unspecified height, and add the div from this answer inside.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, assuming all images are square, we can do it. Add an extra `div` around your image like this:

`<div class="img-container"> 
    <div class="image-wrap">IMAGE HERE</div> 
</div>`

Then we want CSS along the lines of

```
.img-container {
position:relative;
background: #ccc;
width:200px; /* Remove this width */
color:#000;
}

.img-container:before{
content: "";
display: block;
padding-top: 100%; 
}

.image-wrap {
position:  absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

See this in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/jamesking/LNvmY/

You'll want to remove the width set in `.img-container`

Comment: all images have the same width/height ratio = 1, since images are square. Height and width in pixels is also the same for all images.